# 1991 Chevrolet Astro - Vents, AC, Heat Not Working

Tags: chevrolet, hvac, heat

I have a 1991 Chevy Astro. Regardless of what setting (AC, Vent, Defrost, High/Low, etc) I use, I do not appear to be getting any air through any of the vents. I would guess the problem would be related to the blower motor.

However, I obviously do not want to just replace the whole blower motor. What components related to the blower motor could be bad (relays, resistors) as opposed to the actual unit, and how would I go about determining the source? I checked a couple of my fuses and they seemed fine, but I am not quite sure what the next logical step would be.

Thanks.

Comment: If the blower is not operational  it could be the resistor assembly. If the blower is operational it could be the vent doors which I believe are vacuum operated on GM.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usually when the blower resistor goes bad (and they pop like popcorn on certain eras of GM products) they *still* have the highest "#4" blower setting.

There are no "parts" to speak of on your blower motor.  If you need a new one, you need the whole thing.  Fortunately, they are not expensive.

If you are handy, the blower motor is located behind the coolant overflow tank.  There's a heavy "purple"? and red wire coming out of the resistor pack to the actual blower motor...
[image: GM Van Blower Motor Location]

You can apply 12v directly to this connection (with the vehicle off) and see if the motor runs.  If it does, replace the resistor pack.

If it doesn't, your have to replace the blower motor.  It's secured around the flange to the firewall/HVAC housing with a series of 7mm [IIRC] screws, which are always a pain, whether it's behind the glovebox on GM cars, or under the fender on your GM van.

Your local parts store proabably has 30 fans and 100 resistor modules in stock; because that's just how often these fail.  I would not pay more than $50 for a new motor/fan assembly, depending slightly on where you live.  New, it will look something like this:

[image: Blower Motor/Fan Assembly]

---

It's not a hard job.  *Nor is it a fun job.*  If the motor/fan has to come out, take the opportunuty to vaccuum out all the dirt, pine needles and acorns you can reach.

Comment: Thanks so much, I will certainly look into it. Though I am curious, could a vacuum leak cause this issue as well?

Comment: As I mentioned above in my comment . If the blower is fully operational the vents are the next logical step to check they redirect the air flow. If the blower is operational only on the fast speed only then Steve Racer's post is the way to go.